# How to Write OR statement in excel VBA with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

How to Write OR statement in excel VBA with multiple conditions.
I tried it as

```
For i = 1 To 30
a = Sheets("Interface").Range("A" & i).Value
If (Sheets("Interface").Range("A" & i).Value Like "Street*name") Or _
   (UCase(Sheets("Interface").Range("A" & i).Value) Like "Street*address") Or _
   (UCase(Sheets("Interface").Range("A" & i).Value) Like "address") Then
'If a Like "*Street*address*" Then
Sheets("Interface").Range("B" & i).Value = "STREETNAME"
End If
Next i
```

I tried it with simple street*address statement(comment code) but it didn't get into the true code.whats wrong with this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
For i = 1 To 30

    a = UCase(Sheets("Interface").Range("A" & i).Value)

    If a Like "STREET*NAME" Or a Like "STREET*ADDRESS" Or _
                               a Like "ADDRESS" Then

        Sheets("Interface").Range("B" & i).Value = "STREETNAME"

    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks ..All sorted now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with VB/VBA is that if you write compound Or statements like this, VB will evaluate every condition, even if the first condition is found to be True. It won't short-circuit.

It's a bit unconventional, but if you want a short-circuit method, you can use a Select Case, like this:

```
Select Case True
    Case a Like b, _
         a Like c, _
         a Like d, _

        Debug.Print "True"

    Case Else
        Debug.Print "False"

End Select
```